# How Can we have both Authentication on API gateway (AWS IAM and lambda authorizer)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

On AWS Authentication i.e at method execution either we can have authentication on the basis of AWS IAM or custom one i.e lambda authorizer.
How can we have both?